# SQL. Объединение таблиц с суммированием

Tags: sql, join

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT vpl.id, brfv.POVFSC "сумма"
FROM vpl.popen vpl

/*сумма*/
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  id, povfsc FROM PF.POVFSC
    WHERE (id, sroks) IN (SELECT id, MAX(sroks) FROM PF.POVFSC GROUP BY id)
    and (srokpo >= CURRENT DATE or srokpo is NULL) and pripovfsc<>'10'
) brfv on brfv.id=vpl.id
) where id='037102051792985465455579756001'
```

Получается такая выборка в три строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вместо трёх строк вывести одну, содержащую id и общую сумму?

Я могу посчитать сумму вот так:

```
SELECT sum(povfsc) as "сумма" FROM
(
SELECT vpl.id, brfv.POVFSC
FROM vpl.popen vpl

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  id, povfsc FROM PF.POVFSC
    WHERE (id, sroks) IN (SELECT id, MAX(sroks) FROM PF.POVFSC GROUP BY id) 
         and (srokpo >= CURRENT DATE or srokpo is NULL) and pripovfsc<>'10'
) brfv on brfv.id=vpl.id
) where id='037102051792985465455579756001'
```

но не получается потом объединить полученную сумму с id и другими полями из таблицы vpl.popen в одной строке.

Вот структура таблицы PF.POVFSC на всякий случай:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всем спасибо за подсказки, всё получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
    vpl.id
  , sum (brfv.POVFSC) as  "сумма"
 FROM
   vpl.popen vpl
  /*сумма*/
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT  
         id
        ,povfsc 
      FROM
        PF.POVFSC
      WHERE 
          (id, sroks) IN (SELECT id, MAX(sroks) FROM PF.POVFSC GROUP BY id)
          and (srokpo >= CURRENT DATE or srokpo is NULL) and pripovfsc<>'10'
 ) brfv on brfv.id=vpl.id
  where 
    vpl.id='037102051792985465455579756001'
 group by
    vpl.id
```

Comment: если у вас всегда по одному конкретному ид будет считаться то group by из запроса надо а в select оставить только sum (brfv.POVFSC) as  "сумма", если будет много ид и по каждому надо будет вывести сумму тогда с группировкой как я написал.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, мне кажется один селект лишний

```
SELECT vpl.id, sum(brfv.POVFSC)       "сумма" 
FROM vpl.popen vpl /*сумма*/ 
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT id, povfsc 
FROM PF.POVFSC 
WHERE (id, sroks) IN (SELECT id, MAX(sroks) FROM PF.POVFSC GROUP BY id) 
and (srokpo >= CURRENT DATE or srokpo is NULL) 
and pripovfsc<>'10' ) brfv on brfv.id=vpl.id  
where id='037102051792985465455579756001' group by vpl.id
```

Исправил, была лишняя закрывающая скобка.

Comment: Так если удалить первый селект, то останется незакрытая скобка в последней строке.

Comment: Прошу прощения. В какой таблице должно проверяться условие and pripovfsc<>'10' ?

Comment: В таблице PF.POVFSC. Я в исходный вопрос добавил скрин со структурой этой таблицы.

Comment: Попробуйте так, там была лишняя закрывающая скобка

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT vpl.id, sum(brfv.POVFSC) "сумма"
FROM vpl.popen vpl

/*сумма*/
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  id, povfsc FROM PF.POVFSC
    WHERE (id, sroks) IN (SELECT id, MAX(sroks) FROM PF.POVFSC GROUP BY id)
    and (srokpo >= CURRENT DATE or srokpo is NULL) and pripovfsc<>'10'
) brfv on brfv.id=vpl.id
) where id='037102051792985465455579756001' group by id
```

Comment: Ошибка:`ERROR [42803] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0119N An expression starting with "ID" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified. SQLSTATE=42803`
Возможно это особенность DB2 SQL. Вот тут есть описание 
 проблемы, но не могу прикрутить к своему примеру: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC82396

Comment: @J.Doe вероятно, это из-за того, что в самом конце должно быть не просто id, а vpl.id

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужна группировка. Добавьте к запросу предложение `GROUP BY vpl.id`, а имя колонки, которую надо просуммировать, передайте аггрегирующей функции SUM. В результате этого СУБД отсортирует результат по указанной колонке, просуммирует значения во втором столбце, у которых совпадают id, и выдаст как ответ сумму по каждому id.